# How to mock just android.util.Log.d(tag, msg)?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, robolectric

I have several `android.util.Log.d(tag, msg);` calls I want to bypass in a logic unit-test (i.e. not instrumentation: runs on PC, not on android).

So I employed `@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)` on my unit-test class.

But now, when I call `ProtectionDomain pd = aClassObject.getProtectionDomain();`, I get this error on `pd`:

```
ProtectionDomain  (null <no signer certificates>)
     org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.InstrumentingClassLoader@4ad7f3e3
     <no principals>
     null
```

How can I mock just `android.util.Log.d(tag, msg)`?

Comment: Is `@SmallTest` working for plain unit tests?

Comment: I was always thinking it is only for instrumental tests https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/TPy1EeSaSg8

Comment: @EugenMartynov, I removed the `@SmallTest` from question, it was mainly for our team, please ignore it - it's not the issue here, sorry for that...

Comment: I would wrap this call to some class and mock it under test

Comment: @EugenMartynov, this is what I'm currently doing, but then what is `Robolectric` for?

Comment: `Robolectric` is not silver bullet, but it allows me to run my 3k tests within 1.5 minutes

Comment: It is not supported by google also

Comment: @EugenMartynov, what is not supported by Google? `Robolectric` ?

Comment: Yes, it is not supported and not recommended by Google